# htaccess rewrite rule causing 404 in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a WordPress page with a custom page template that I am then sending GET data. I want to rewrite http://example.com/blue/green to http://example.com/blue/?id=green

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blue/green/?$ /blue/?id=green [NC,L]
```

Taking this to the next step, I want to make green generic as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blue/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /blue/?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

These rules are placed above the WordPress rules in the .htaccess file, but keep producing 404 errors.

However, if I use a 301 redirect, it does work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blue/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /blue/?id=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Or if I put in the absolute URL it works too:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blue/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ http://example.com/blue/?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, both of these cause the URL to change which I don't want, if possible. So what is wrong with the first two htaccess statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out in the end. Have to use WordPress rewrite functions instead of htaccess directly. Here is my code in theme functions.php

```
// Add query tags
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'stats_rewrite_tag' );
function stats_rewrite_tag( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}

// Add to htaccess
function stats_rewrite_rule() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'blue(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?pagename=blue&slug=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( false );
}
add_action('init', 'stats_rewrite_rule');
```